# ContentProvider - Do i need an entry in the manifest file?

Tags: android

i have a simple question. 
Do i need for the use of a content provider an entry in the manifest file?

The content provider is only for my own application. I don't want to share informations with other apps (at the moment). I have an example open source project, where content providers are used a lot, but there is no "provider" entry in the manifest file... how does this works?

When i'm starting my app i get these error

> "Failed to find provider info for...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It should point to your custom `ContentProvider` class. Inside your `<application></application>` block.

```
<provider
    android:name=".MyAppContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.myapp.provider"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: OKay... Thanks. Just wonder how this open source project could work without the declaration..

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

From the documentation:

```
All content providers in your application must be defined in a <provider> element in the 
manifest file; otherwise, the system is unaware of them and doesn't run them.
```

Taken from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare content provider in menifest file also:-
Like another components of android ,content provider is also  declare inside the application tag of menifest file .

```
<application>
<provider android:name="com.tyczj.bowling.mnp"
    android:authorities="com.tyczj.bowling.mnp">
</provider>
</application
```